# jqgrid with static data in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

can anybody help me in binding jqgrid with datatable
i am now doing the prototype of jqgrid where i am binding data to jqgrid using 'datatype:local' and binding data writing code only in aspx page
but now i want to bind data which has to come from .cs page(with static datatable)

my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

             jQuery("#list47").jqGrid({
                 data: mydata,
                 datatype: "local",
                 height: 150,
                 rowNum: 2,
                 rowList: [2, 4, 5, 10],
                 colNames: ['Inv No', 'Image', 'Date', 'Client', 'Amount', 'Tax', 'Total', 'Notes'],
                 colModel: [
    { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 60, sorttype: "int" },
     { name: 'productimage', index: 'id', width: 100, sorttype: "int", align: "center" },
    { name: 'invdate', index: 'invdate', width: 90, sorttype: "date", formatter: "date" },
    { name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 100 },
    { name: 'amount', index: 'amount', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float", formatter: "number" },
    { name: 'tax', index: 'tax', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
    { name: 'total', index: 'total', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
    { name: 'note', index: 'note', width: 150, sortable: false}],
         pager: '#plist47',
                   sortname: 'id',
                   viewrecords: true,
                   caption: "Manipulating Array Data" 

             });
             var mydata = [
    { id: "1", productimage: "<a href='JQgridNir.aspx'><img src='../images/0000110.jpg' border='0'/></a>", invdate: "2010-05-24", name: "test", note: "note", tax: "10.00", total: "2111.00" },
    { id: "2", productimage: "<img src='../images/0000110.jpg' />", invdate: "2010-05-25", name: "test2", note: "note2", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "3", productimage: "<img src='../images/0000110.jpg' />", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "4", productimage: "<img src='../images/0000110.jpg' />", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "5", productimage: "<img src='../images/0000110.jpg' />", invdate: "2007-10-05", name: "test2", note: "note2", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "6", productimage: "<img src='../images/0000110.jpg' />", invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test3", note: "note3", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "7", productimage: "<img src='../images/0000110.jpg' />", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "8", productimage: "<img src='../images/0000110.jpg' />", invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "21.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "9", productimage: "<img src='../images/0000110.jpg' />", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "11", productimage: "<img src='../images/0000110.jpg' />", invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "12", productimage: "<img src='../images/0000110.jpg' />", invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "13", productimage: "<img src='../images/0000110.jpg' />", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "14", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "15", invdate: "2007-10-05", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "16", invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "17", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "18", invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "19", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "21", invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "22", invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "23", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "24", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "25", invdate: "2007-10-05", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "26", invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "27", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "28", invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "29", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" }
];
             for (var i = 0; i <= mydata.length; i++)
                 jQuery("#list47").jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, mydata[i]);
         });
```

Comment: some columns has no values. I think that you would use default values.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout this example. Tested in IE.

```
<html>
<head>

<link href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>                        

<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>                        

</head>
<body>

<table id="list4"></table>


<script type="text/javascript"> 
 $(function()
 {

 jQuery("#list4").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    height: 250,
    colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int"},
        {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90, sorttype:"date"},
        {name:'name',index:'name', width:100},
        {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},
        {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},     
        {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right",sorttype:"float"},      
        {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false}       
    ],
    multiselect: true,
    caption: "Manipulating Array Data"
});
var mydata = [
        {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
        {id:"2",invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
        {id:"3",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
        {id:"4",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
        {id:"5",invdate:"2007-10-05",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
        {id:"6",invdate:"2007-09-06",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
        {id:"7",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
        {id:"8",invdate:"2007-10-03",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
        {id:"9",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}
        ];
for(var i=0;i<=mydata.length;i++)
    jQuery("#list4").jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,mydata[i]);


 });


</script> 

</body>
</html>
```